# How to merge two datasets according to DATE in R - with code

Tags: r, date, merge, combinations

I am trying to do the following. I have a dataset1 that goes from 2015-01-31 up until 2021-06-30:

```
dataset1_dates=c("2015-01-31","2015-02-28","2015-03-31","2015-04-30","2015-05-31","2015-06-30","2015-07-31","2015-08-31","2015-09-30","2015-10-31","2015-11-30","2015-12-31","2016-01-31","2016-02-29","2016-03-31","2016-04-30","2016-05-31","2016-06-30","2016-07-31","2016-08-31","2016-09-30","2016-10-31","2016-11-30","2016-12-31","2017-01-31","2017-02-28","2017-03-31","2017-04-30","2017-05-31","2017-06-30","2017-07-31","2017-08-31","2017-09-30","2017-10-31","2017-11-30","2017-12-31","2018-01-31","2018-02-28","2018-03-31","2018-04-30","2018-05-31","2018-06-30","2018-07-31","2018-08-31","2018-09-30","2018-10-31","2018-11-30","2018-12-31","2019-01-31","2019-02-28","2019-03-31","2019-04-30","2019-05-31","2019-06-30","2019-07-31","2019-08-31","2019-09-30","2019-10-31","2019-11-30","2019-12-31","2020-01-31","2020-02-29","2020-03-31","2020-04-30","2020-05-31","2020-06-30","2020-07-31","2020-08-31","2020-09-30","2020-10-31","2020-11-30","2020-12-31","2021-01-31","2021-02-28","2021-03-31","2021-04-30","2021-05-31","2021-06-30")
# add dates
dataset1 <- expand.grid(Organisation = c("A123","B234","C456"),
                       Date = dataset1_dates)
  
## sort
dataset1 <- dataset1[order(dataset1$Organisation, dataset1$Date),]
## reset id
rownames(dataset1) <- NULL

dataset1$Organisation <- as.character(dataset1$Organisation)
dataset1$Date <- as.Date(dataset1$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Then I have a dataset2 that tells me at specific points in time the performance of each organisation at the time of inspection:

```
dataset2 <- read.table(
  text = "
Organisation    Date_inspection     Performance
A123            2015-01-31          Good
A123            2016-01-14          OK
B234            2017-06-14          Inadequate
C456            2015-06-30          OK
C456            2016-02-10          Inspected but not rated
C456            2018-05-18          Good
C456            2020-03-21          OK",
  header = TRUE)

dataset2$Organisation <- as.character(dataset2$Organisation)
dataset2$Date_inspection <- as.Date(dataset2$Date_inspection, format="%Y-%m-%d")
dataset2$Performance <- as.character(dataset2$Performance)
```

I would like to assign to each month *after* inspection, including the month of the inspection, the performance category of the organisation.

I would also like to consider months prior to the 1st inspection as equal to the performance category at date of 1st inspection.

Expected result:

```
Date        |   Organisation    |     Performance     |
2015-01-31  |   A123            |     Good            |
2015-02-28  |   A123            |     Good            |
2015-03-31  |   A123            |     Good            |
...
2016-01-31  |   A123            |     OK              |
...
2021-06-30  |   A123            |     OK              |
2015-01-31  |   B234            |     Inadequate      |
2015-02-28  |   B234            |     Inadequate      |
2015-03-31  |   B234            |     Inadequate      |
...
2021-06-30  |   B234            |     Inadequate      |
2015-01-31  |   C456            |     OK              |
2015-02-28  |   C456            |     OK              |
2015-03-31  |   C456            |     OK              |
...
2016-02-29  |   C456            |     OK              |
...
2018-05-31  |   C456            |     Good            |
2018-06-30  |   C456            |     Good            |
...
2020-03-31  |   C456            |     OK              |
...
2021-06-30  |   C456            |     OK              |
```

Any ideas on how to do this in R?

Comment: Your output has 'Location' but neither dataset1 nor dataset2 contains it.

Comment: Sorry Dirk, I missed these comments/answers, did not get notified. I've edited my question now, there is no location in final output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notes on how to remedy your broken `read.table()` expression:
Currently the whitespace in the values of your Performance column is causing an error when parsing it into the table. An easy remedy is to recode your values prior to importing it as follows (note that the whitespace in the string "Inspected but not rated", has been replaced with "_", resulting the value "Inspected_but_not_rated").

```
dataset2 <- read.table(
  text = "
Organisation    Date_inspection     Performance
A123            2015-01-31          Good
A123            2016-01-14          OK
B234            2017-06-14          Inadequate
C456            2015-06-30          OK
C456            2016-02-10          Inspected_but_not_rated
C456            2018-05-18          Good
C456            2020-03-21          OK",
  header = TRUE)
```

We can now insert the whitespace back into the string as follows:

```
dataset2$Performance <- with(
  dataset2, 
  gsub("_", " ", Performance)
)
```

Resulting in the `dataset2` object you see below.

Base R (amended) solution (in line with additional requests in comments):
Firstly your `dataset2` `data.frame` object is now broken so we will start using:

```
dataset2 <- structure(list(Organisation = c("A123", "A123", "B234", "C456", 
"C456", "C456", "C456"), Date_inspection = structure(c(16466, 
16814, 17331, 16616, 16841, 17669, 18342), class = "Date"), Performance = c("Good", 
"OK", "Inadequate", "OK", "Inspected but not rated", "Good", 
"OK")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Secondly, all we have to do in this amended case is re-code "Inspected but not rated" to `NA_character_`. Please see the revised solution below:

```
# Recode Inspected but not rated to an NA of type 
# character: clean_df2 => data.frame
clean_df2 <- transform(
  dataset2,
  Performance = gsub(
    "Inspected but not rated",
    NA_character_,
    Performance
    )
)

# Expand the "dataset2" to months which the ratings
# are considered applicable over: 
# inspectionsApplicable => data.frame
inspectionsApplicable <- unique(
  data.frame(
    do.call(
      rbind, 
      lapply(
        with(
          clean_df2,
          split(
            clean_df2, 
            Organisation
          )
        ),
        function(x){
          x$Month_inspected <- as.Date(
            strftime(
              x$Date_inspection,
              "%Y-%m-01"
            )
          )
          x$MinMonthInData <- as.Date(
            strftime(
              min(
                dataset1$Date[
                  match(
                    x$Organisation, 
                    dataset1$Organisation
                  )
                ]
              ), 
              "%Y-%m-01"
            )
          )
          data.frame(
            Organisation = c(
              x$Organisation[1],
              x$Organisation
            ),
            Months = c(
              as.Date(unique(x$MinMonthInData)),
              as.Date(x$Month_inspected, "%Y-%m-%d")
            ),
            Performance = c(
              x$Performance[
                which.max(
                  !(
                    is.na(
                      x$Performance
                      )
                    )
                  )
                ],
              x$Performance
            )
          )
        }
      )
    ),
    row.names = NULL
  )
)

# Left join the tables, and forward fill, 
# the inspection category: ir_res => data.frame
res <- within(
  merge(
    transform(
      with(
        dataset1,
        dataset1[order(Organisation, Date),]
      ), 
      Months = as.Date(
        strftime(
          Date,
          "%Y-%m-01"
        )
      )
    ),
    inspectionsApplicable,
    by = c(
      "Organisation",
      "Months"
    ),
    all.x = TRUE
  ),
  {
    Performance <- na.omit(
      Performance
    )[
      cumsum(
        !(
          is.na(
            Performance
          )
        )
      )
    ]
    rm(Months)
  }
)
```

Base R (Original) solution:

```
# Expand the "dataset2" to months which the ratings
# are considered applicable over: 
# inspectionsApplicable => data.frame
inspectionsApplicable <- unique(
  data.frame(
    do.call(
      rbind, 
      lapply(
        with(
          dataset2, 
          split(
            dataset2, 
            Organisation
          )
        ),
        function(x){
          x$Month_inspected <- as.POSIXlt(
            strftime(
              x$Date_inspection,
              "%Y-%m-01"
            )
          )
          x$MinMonthInData <- as.Date(
            strftime(
              min(
                dataset1$Date[
                  match(
                    x$Organisation, 
                    dataset1$Organisation
                    )
                  ]
                ), 
              "%Y-%m-01"
              )
            )
          data.frame(
            Organisation = c(
              x$Organisation[1],
              x$Organisation
            ),
            Months = c(
              as.Date(unique(x$MinMonthInData)),
              as.Date(x$Month_inspected, "%Y-%m-%d")
            ),
           Performance = c(
             x$Performance[1],
             x$Performance
            )
          )
        }
      )
    ),
    row.names = NULL
  )
)

# Left join the tables, and forward fill, 
# the inspection category: ir_res => data.frame
res <- transform(
  merge(
    transform(
      with(
        dataset1,
        dataset1[order(Date),]
      ), 
      Months = as.Date(
        strftime(
          Date,
          "%Y-%m-01"
        )
      )
    ),
    inspectionsApplicable,
    by = c(
      "Organisation",
      "Months"
    ),
    all.x = TRUE
  ),
  Performance = na.omit(
    Performance
    )[
      cumsum(
        !(
          is.na(
            Performance
            )
          )
        )
      ]
)
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly, thank you. One last point - I've edited my question with this scenario. E.g. for C456, on 2016-02-10, Performance = "Inspected but not rated", so I would like to assign the previous Performance instead (in this case, "OK") up until the next Performance. Is it easy to add this to the code?

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues typically it's bad etiquette to edit questions once an answer has been provided without accepting it. However, I have amended my solution to your new question. Please see above and upvote and accept it if it does what you require.

Comment: Sorry, I have done it now. Thank you - This works great, but my dataset2 here is just an example of my real dataset2. So I do not know exactly what I need to do to my real dataset2 to accommodate for step 1 (Firstly your dataset2 data.frame object is now broken so we will start using:..). In my case, I import dataset2 and after some steps, I end up with those 3 columns but many more rows. Can you just advise on this please?

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues replace the spaces with underscores in the Performance text string values and then use gsub to replace them once you read in your data.frame.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand what you mean. Is it possible to include some code in your answer that represents what you mean? Thank you

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues Please see the top of my answer above.

Comment: Thank you- works perfectly. What should I do now in terms of giving you the +50 points?

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues Please click the bounty icon. For details see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, I think I did it. Thanks again for your help on this.

Comment: I did a mistake- instead of assigning the performance category to each month after inspection, the rule is to assign it to each month before inspection and including the month of inspection. Then the months after last inspection are equal to performance category at date of last inspection. Do you think this is something easier to accommodate in your code? I can raise a new question with this modification

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues Please raise another question and I will answer it. It should be a relatively easy fix.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've just posted it: "How to merge 2 datasets according to DATE".

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach using dplyr. Note that this requires `Organisation` to be `character` in both datasets (i.e. no conversion using `as.factor`).

```
lookup <- function(x, y) {
  dataset2 %>% 
  filter(Organisation == x, Date_inspection <= y) %>% 
  pull(Performance) %>%
  last(
    default = dataset2 %>% 
    filter(Organisation == x) %>% 
    slice_min(Date_inspection) %>% 
    pull(Performance)
  ) 
}

# add `Performance` by applying `lookup` over `organisation` and `Date`
dataset1 %>%
  mutate(Performance = map2_chr(Organisation, Date, lookup))
```

The idea is to use a function `lookup` that `pull`s the `Performance` value for the organisation's last inspection. If that value doesn't exist (because there is no `Date_inspection <= y`) we use the first inspection date for that organisation.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Both 'Organisation' and 'Performance' are characters now (I've edited the code in my question), but I get the following error when I run your code: > dataset1 %>%
+   mutate(Performance = map2_chr(Organisation, Date, lookup))
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `Performance`.
ℹ `Performance = map2_chr(Organisation, Date, lookup)`.
x Result 79 must be a single string, not a character vector of length 0
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred. Do you know what might be happening?

Comment: This is the error message I get if I run 'Performance' as factor: > dataset1 %>%
+   mutate(Performance = map2_chr(Organisation, Date, lookup))
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `Performance`.
ℹ `Performance = map2_chr(Organisation, Date, lookup)`.
x Result 79 must be a single string, not a vector of class `factor` and of length 0

Comment: I forgot to include an argument to `slice_min()`. Could you please retry (with character organisation)?

Comment: Thanks Martin. I tried your code above with slice_min(Date_inspection) but still get the same error: Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `Performance`.
ℹ `Performance = map2_chr(Organisation, Date, lookup)`.
x Result 79 must be a single string, not a character vector of length 0. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right way, but neither your `dataset1` nor `dataset2` contain the column `Location`.

If this column is missing in your main data too, then this may be the first step to look into.

I can edit my answer if needed.

Comment: I am sorry, I missed these comments/answers, did not get notified.  I've edited my question now, there is no location in final output. I cannot see your answer, did you post it already?